# Automatically set property value from agenda view

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm trying to create a function that will set a tag and a property with current timestamp to an header entry selected in agenda.

This is what I came up with so far, it adds the tag but it does not add the property at all:

```
(defun my-org-agenda-set-focus-for-task ()
  "Add :focus: tag and a PROPERTY with current timestamp to the item selected"
  (interactive)
  (when (eq major-mode 'org-agenda-mode)
    (org-agenda-set-tags "focus" "ON")
    (org-set-property "FOCUS" (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))))
```

I also tried to use org-agenda-set-property but it crashes saying that I'm passing to many arguments. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

`org-set-property` assumes that you are at the right place to set the property. There is an `org-agenda-set-property` which gets you to the right place but then calls `org-set-property` interactively to get the property and the value to set. But you can mix-and-match and roll your own:

```
(defun my-org-agenda-set-focus-for-task ()
  "Add :focus: tag and a PROPERTY with current timestamp to the item selected"
  (interactive)
  (when (eq major-mode 'org-agenda-mode)
     (org-agenda-set-tags "focus" "ON")
     (my-org-agenda-set-property "FOCUS" (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))))


(defun my-org-agenda-set-property (prop val)
  "Set a property for the current headline."
  (org-agenda-check-no-diary)
  (let* ((hdmarker (or (org-get-at-bol 'org-hd-marker)
           (org-agenda-error)))
     (buffer (marker-buffer hdmarker))
     (pos (marker-position hdmarker))
     (inhibit-read-only t)
     newhead)
    (org-with-remote-undo buffer
       (with-current-buffer buffer
          (widen)
          (goto-char pos)
          (org-show-context 'agenda)
          (org-set-property prop val)))))
```

where `my-org-agenda-set-property` is almost an exact copy of the built-in `org-agenda-set-property` except for the last line, where `(call-interactively 'org-set-property)` has been replaced with `(org-set-property prop val)`.